# "Bad directive" value error when converting to Pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp' : ['Wednesday, Apr 4/04/22 at 17:02',
                                  'Saturday, Apr 4/23/22 at 15:45'],
                        'foo' : [1, 2]
                       })

df
    timestamp                          foo
0   Wednesday, Apr 4/04/22 at 17:02    1
1   Saturday, Apr 4/23/22 at 15:45     2
```

I'm trying to convert the `timestamp` column to a datetime object so that I can add a `day_of_week` column.

My attempt:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],
                                 format='%A, %b %-m/%-d/%y at %H:%M')
df['day_of_week'] = df['timestamp'].dt.day_name()
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%A, %b %-m/%-d/%y at %H:%M'
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the format without the `-`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],
                                 format='%A, %b %m/%d/%y at %H:%M')
df['day_of_week'] = df['timestamp'].dt.day_name()
```

*NB. `to_datetime` is quite flexible on the provided data, note how the incorrect day of week was just ignored.*

output:

```
            timestamp  foo day_of_week
0 2022-04-04 17:02:00  1    Monday    
1 2022-04-23 15:45:00  2    Saturday
```